# select multiple sum how to filter by date correctly

Tags: sql, date, select, sum, between

Here is what I have currently that does not filter anything by createdDate.

```
SELECT [employeeID]
      ,employeeName
      ,isnull((SELECT SUM(case when clientID != 10 then timeSpent else 0 end)),0) as 'billable'

      ,isnull((SELECT SUM(case when clientID = 10 then timeSpent else 0 end)),0) as 'nonBillable'
FROM [myDB].[dbo].[myTable]
group by employeeID,employeeName
```

which outputs:

```
employeeID employeeName billable nonbillable
---------- ------------ -------- -----------
1          tom          5230     2302
2          dick         25       8439
3          harry        2430     9433
```

accurate output would be similar but with sum of values only within the date range:

```
employeeID employeeName billable nonbillable
---------- ------------ -------- -----------
1          tom          35       5
2          dick         25       15
3          harry        2        48
```

[myTable] has the following fields: employeeID,employeeName,clientID,timeSpent,createdDate

I need to be able to add a filter in to each of the select sum statements similar to the following:  WHERE createdDate BETWEEN ('2012-10-01') AND ('2012-10-07')

The following variations all fail either with SQL Errors or inaccurate output:

```
SELECT [employeeID]
      ,employeeName
      ,isnull((SELECT SUM(case when clientID != 10 then timeSpent else 0 end)),0) as 'billable'
      ,isnull((SELECT SUM(case when clientID = 10 then timeSpent else 0 end)),0) as 'nonBillable'
FROM [myDB].[dbo].[myTable]
WHERE createdDate BETWEEN ('2012-10-01') AND ('2012-10-07')
group by employeeID,employeeName

SELECT DISTINCT [employeeID]
      ,employeeName
      ,isnull((SELECT SUM(case when clientID != 10 then timeSpent else 0 end)),0) as 'billable'
      ,isnull((SELECT SUM(case when clientID = 10 then timeSpent else 0 end)),0) as 'nonBillable'
FROM [myDB].[dbo].[myTable]
WHERE createdDate BETWEEN ('2012-10-01') AND ('2012-10-07')
group by employeeID,employeeName

SELECT [employeeID]
      ,employeeName
      ,isnull((SELECT SUM(case when clientID != 10 then timeSpent else 0 end)WHERE createdDate BETWEEN ('2012-10-01') AND ('2012-10-07')),0) as 'billable'
      ,isnull((SELECT SUM(case when clientID = 10 then timeSpent else 0 end)WHERE createdDate BETWEEN ('2012-10-01') AND ('2012-10-07')),0) as 'nonBillable'
FROM [myDB].[dbo].[myTable]
group by employeeID,employeeName,createdDate
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should specify the SQL platform - this looks like SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query should give you the correct results

```
SELECT [employeeID] 
      ,employeeName 
      ,isnull((SELECT SUM(case when clientID != 10 then timeSpent else 0 end)),0) as 'billable' 
      ,isnull((SELECT SUM(case when clientID = 10 then timeSpent else 0 end)),0) as 'nonBillable' 
FROM [myDB].[dbo].[myTable] 
WHERE createdDate BETWEEN '2012-10-01' AND '2012-10-07'
group by employeeID,employeeName
```

However, if `createdDate` is a datetime type, then it will only return values between '2012-01-01 00:00' and '2012-10-07 00:00' - nothing after 2012-10-07 00:01. Ideally you would specify the filter dates as dates, rather than strings.

Comment: You are Correct.  I must have had something slightly different when I ran it before posting the question.  Thank you.